# Javascript: How to add a reset/play again function? Please read

Tags: javascript

I posted the "Please Read" because this question does sound like a few others, but i've looked at those ones, and i still cant figure out how to add a successful rester button. What im trying to say, i have a game area. Once the player fails, they have to hit "Run Code" to restart, but a restart button under the Accelerate button would be awesome. I hope you can help. Here is my present code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:7px solid #00aaff;
    background-color: #00aaff;
}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="startGame()">
<br>


<button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)"onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)"><p style="height:0px;width:793px"><p style="font-family:Wide Latin"><font color="#00aaff">Click to Accelerate</button></button><p><font color="turquoise">
<p style="font-family:Arial Rounded MT Bold">☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️Click the ACCELERATE button to start the game☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️<p><font color="Orange"></p>
<p style="font-family:Agency FB">How long can you stay alive? Use the ACCELERATE button to stay in the air.</p>
<script>

var myGamePiece;
var myBackground;
var myObstacles = [];
var myScore;
var gameSpeed = 1;

function startGame() {
    myBackground = new component(800, 380,"http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/29/297846/2789895-cool+space+backgrounds+desktop+hd+wallpaper.jpg", 0, 0, "image");
    myGamePiece = new component(50, 50, "http://images.tourismholdings.com/public/2016/02/56bd3c714ecc6.png", 35, 200, "image");
    myScore = new component("30px", "Algerian", "turquoise", 15, 30, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 800;
        this.canvas.height = 380;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
    stop : function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
  if (type == "image") {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = color;
  }
      this.type = type;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0; 
    this.gravity = 0.05;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;   
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
    if (type == "image") {
      ctx.drawImage(this.image, 
        this.x, 
        this.y,
        this.width, this.height);
    }
    else if (this.type == "text") {
      ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
    }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
        this.hitBottom();
    }  
     this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;
        }
    }
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x; 
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {

    var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            myGameArea.stop();
            return;
        }
    }
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
        x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
        minHeight = 20;
        maxHeight = 200;
        height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
        minGap = 150;
        maxGap = 250;
        gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
        myObstacles.push(new component(15, height, "https://orig00.deviantart.net/bb11/f/2014/127/f/e/hexagon_wallpaper___version_3_by_designedby_jack-d7hh9xo.png", x, 0, "image"));
        myObstacles.push(new component(15, height, "https://orig00.deviantart.net/bb11/f/2014/127/f/e/hexagon_wallpaper___version_3_by_designedby_jack-d7hh9xo.png", x, height + gap, "image"));
        gameSpeed = gameSpeed - 1;    
    }
    myBackground.newPos();   
    myBackground.update();
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        myObstacles[i].x += gameSpeed;
        myObstacles[i].update();
    }
    myScore.text="Space Run                                                         SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
    myScore.update();
    myGamePiece.newPos();   
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}

function moveup() {
    myGamePiece.speedY = -1;
}

function movedown() {
    myGamePiece.speedY = 1;
}

function moveleft() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = -1;
}

function moveright() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 1;
}

function clearmove() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
    myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
}
function accelerate(n) {
    myGamePiece.gravity = n;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
<audio <embed loop="true" autoplay="autoplay">
     <source src="http://mp3-128.cdn107.com/music/08/94/16/0894161495.mp3 " />     
 </audio>

<p style="font-family:Wide Latin"<p><font color="#fafafa">This Game Was Created By Landon Sturtevant</p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#f3f3f3";
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('img_tree.png')";
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm honestly trying not to sound abrasive here, but do you really expect us to read through all that code and do your work for you, with zero explanation on your part...? We're happy to help if you get stuck on a specific problem, but you need to make an effort on your own first. Have you tried implementing this button yourself? What did you try? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Well, no, it would just be great to write out a code function that would work. I cant find out what the code for a restart button is, but i have a I guess i wasnt clear

Comment: StackOverflow is for discussing problems that you encounter while writing your code, understanding why those problems occurred, and finding a solution. It's not a "help wanted" column.

Comment: I have used a restart function: <button id="playagain" onclick="clickPlayagain()">Play again</button> and added it right under my accelerate button.

Comment: Okay, and what does the `clickPlayagain()` function do? Where did you define it?

Comment: I added the "Clickplay Again function on line 20 i put it in between <script> and <p style="font-family:Agency FB">How long can you stay alive? Use the ACCELERATE button to stay in the air.</p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just modified your code, adding an empty div in your html and when you lose the game in update area, a button is created that once it's clicked it will reload the page. This is the simplest implementation, but I recommend you using a more complex solution like having a function called game over that resets all the variables of the game to the initial position and introduce it on the button that I made.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:7px solid #00aaff;
    background-color: #00aaff;
}
</style>
</head>

<body onload="startGame()">
<br>


<button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)"onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)"><p style="height:0px;width:793px"><p style="font-family:Wide Latin"><font color="#00aaff">Click to Accelerate</button></button><p><font color="turquoise">
<div class="resetButton"></div>
<p style="font-family:Arial Rounded MT Bold">☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️Click the ACCELERATE button to start the game☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️☄️<p><font color="Orange"></p>
<p style="font-family:Agency FB">How long can you stay alive? Use the ACCELERATE button to stay in the air.</p>
<script>

var myGamePiece;
var myBackground;
var myObstacles = [];
var myScore;
var gameSpeed = 1;

function startGame() {
    myBackground = new component(800, 380,"http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/29/297846/2789895-cool+space+backgrounds+desktop+hd+wallpaper.jpg", 0, 0, "image");
    myGamePiece = new component(50, 50, "http://images.tourismholdings.com/public/2016/02/56bd3c714ecc6.png", 35, 200, "image");
    myScore = new component("30px", "Algerian", "turquoise", 15, 30, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 800;
        this.canvas.height = 380;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
    stop : function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
  if (type == "image") {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = color;
  }
      this.type = type;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0; 
    this.gravity = 0.05;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;   
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
    if (type == "image") {
      ctx.drawImage(this.image, 
        this.x, 
        this.y,
        this.width, this.height);
    }
    else if (this.type == "text") {
      ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
      ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
    }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
        this.hitBottom();
    }  
     this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;
        }
    }
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x; 
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {

    var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            myGameArea.stop();
            document.getElementsByClassName("resetButton")[0].innerHTML='<button onclick="location.reload();">Restart The game</button>';
            return;
        }
    }
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
        x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
        minHeight = 20;
        maxHeight = 200;
        height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
        minGap = 150;
        maxGap = 250;
        gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
        myObstacles.push(new component(15, height, "https://orig00.deviantart.net/bb11/f/2014/127/f/e/hexagon_wallpaper___version_3_by_designedby_jack-d7hh9xo.png", x, 0, "image"));
        myObstacles.push(new component(15, height, "https://orig00.deviantart.net/bb11/f/2014/127/f/e/hexagon_wallpaper___version_3_by_designedby_jack-d7hh9xo.png", x, height + gap, "image"));
        gameSpeed = gameSpeed - 1;    
    }
    myBackground.newPos();   
    myBackground.update();
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        myObstacles[i].x += gameSpeed;
        myObstacles[i].update();
    }
    myScore.text="Space Run                                                         SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
    myScore.update();
    myGamePiece.newPos();   
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}

function moveup() {
    myGamePiece.speedY = -1;
}

function movedown() {
    myGamePiece.speedY = 1;
}

function moveleft() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = -1;
}

function moveright() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 1;
}

function clearmove() {
    myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
    myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
}
function accelerate(n) {
    myGamePiece.gravity = n;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
<audio <embed loop="true" autoplay="autoplay">
     <source src="http://mp3-128.cdn107.com/music/08/94/16/0894161495.mp3 " />     
 </audio>

<p style="font-family:Wide Latin"<p><font color="#fafafa">This Game Was Created By Landon Sturtevant</p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#f3f3f3";
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('img_tree.png')";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sure, no worries